# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Employee

Tags: spring

it is showing error ,when using this code im my java class

```
    //Get all the Employees
    List employeeList = dao.getAllEmployees();
    System.out.println("*** List of all Employee ***");
    for(Employee emp2 : employeeList)
    {
        System.out.println("Employee ID   ::"+emp2.getId());
        System.out.println("Employee Name ::"+emp2.getName());
        System.out.println("Employee Age  ::"+emp2.getAge());
        System.out.println("Deptartment   ::"+emp2.getDept());
        System.out.println(" *********************");            
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Can you please use the correct formatting for code. Can you please add the complete exception you receive. Also, only having code in the question won't let you post it. This is for a good reason. Give some additional details and explenations.

Comment: You are using a `List` (untyped) and in your `for` loop you are expecting it to contain `Employee` objects. The compiler doesn't allow that (or at least gives a warning). You should use a `List<Employee>` as the type instead.